# Loading animation isn't rendered right away

Tags: javascript, css, .net-6.0, loading

I'm trying to display a loading animation when sending an api to the backend, and hide it when it's done. The problem is, the browser doesn't seem to have rendered the loading unless I add a breakpoint **in the devtools** and execute step by step.

If I remove the devtools breakpoint (at line 4) and pauses with another breakpoint on the backend(through jQuery ajax), I don't see the animation.
If I set a breakpoint at line 6, I do see the animation, but it's of no use since it'll be away just one line right after it. It seems like what should have happended at line 2 only really happens after the apiCalling.

```
1    document.querySelector(".btnGenerate").addEventListener("click", function () {
2        loading.style.display = 'block';
3
4        apiCalling();
5
6        loading.style.display = 'none';
7    })
```

I expect when I pause at backend breakpoints (when the apiCalling() is executed at line 4), I should already see the animation rendered on the browser.

Comment: An `async` function does not pause, it gets executed 'parallel' to the main code, you need to tell your method to pause by using an `await` and returning a `Promise` that resolves when your apiCalling() is done. I presume apiCalling() contains a `fetch` anyway, so you could just return that promise.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are executed in sequence.

First you pass your loading in `display: block;`, then you call the function and finally you pass the loading in `display: none;`. It does not wait for the `apiCalling()` function to finish executing to switch to `display: none;`.

You can bypass that by putting a `setTimeout(function, time);` on your apiCalling function, it will allow you to mark a timeout in the execution of the instructions.

I let you know more about this function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/setTimeout).

Have a nice day!

Comment: Yes, but I would retool the methods to be `async`, allowing an `await apiCalling()` in the middle. its probably using fetch already so it's probably a promise to begin with. Timeouts are just guesses, which isn't ideal.

Comment: If you use JQuery you can use that `beforeSend: function(){$( loading.style.display = 'block' },` and `complete: function(){ loading.style.display = 'none' },`. If you do `const req = new XMLHttpRequest()` use that `req.addEventListener("load", function);` before `req.open("GET", "http://www.example.org/example.txt");`. You can find more about that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Okay, those are all solutions, but try a fetch Promise and `await`. Much easier than these cobbled together library solutions.

Comment: I dont know they solution I'm already a junior developer, I'm going see that. Thank you man! Edit: Thank you for this solution it's the best yeah.

Comment: The above solutions used to be the norm, don't get me wrong, but today we can easily use things like`async` and `await` so I would really suggest getting your teeth into that :) - it would reduce to something like `classList.add; await fetch(); classList.remove;`. Async/await with promises is pretty neat!